# Flutter firestore returning empty array on some documents

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can one explain to me what's going on with with firestore collection fetching.
[image]
[image]

I am able to fecth `buses`collection data under 201 but when I fecth for other 'ids' like 212 I get an empty array when there is clearly data in there.

this is the fecth function

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 Future<dynamic> getBusesByID(int id) async {
    // Create a CollectionReference called users that references the firestore collection
    var lines = firestore.collection('lines').doc('$id').collection('buses');
    var line = await lines.get();

    return line.docs.map((e) => {'id': e.id, ...e.data()}).toList();
  }
```

what is it with the weird behavior?